# orange python 2.7 installation

Tags: python-2.7, orange

I currently have Anaconda python 2.7 and I'm looking to [add the Orange GUI](http://orange.biolab.si/orange2/).  I apologize in advance if this is an amateur question.  When I download the installer for Orange 2.7, it says it is going to install python 2.7 and other packages I know I have.  I've had problems in the past having two versions of python on my computer, so I would assume I want to avoid this issue and not install another python 2.7.

Is there any way to get the Orange Data Mining GUI and keep the Anaconda version of python?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. From command line, install orange with this command `conda install orange` (You must connected to the internet)
2. Type "Yes" and wait until the installation process is finished
3. To run the software, type this command `python -m Orange.OrangeCanvas.main`
   Good luck... :)